# how to find in text for a negative word?

Tags: regex

How i find all lines  not containing this word: "_archive" ???

`XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX _archive 1

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX _archive 2

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX teste 1

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX _archive 3

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX teste 2

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX _archive 4

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX teste 3

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX _archive 5

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX _archive 6

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX _archive 7

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX _archive 8

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX teste 4

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX _archive 9

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX _archive 10

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX _archive 11

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX teste 5`

Thanks

Comment: What language are you using? Are these lines in an array per line? Or one long string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `grep -v`:

```
grep -v _archive inputfile.txt
```

This command prints out each line in `inputfile.txt` that does *not* contain `_archive`.

Answer (score 0):

suppose your file is under "file.txt"

the following unix command would do it

```
grep -v _archive file.txt
```